# SyncAdapter does not run. It's always pending

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

Hello everyone I'm having a really hard time trying to make my syncAdapter to work with the content provider I already have working.

```
ContentResolver.isSyncPending(mConnectedAccount,MyContentProvider.AUTHORITY)
```

always return true.
Considerations

- All authoritie keys and account types are correct;
- I called `setIsSyncable` and also `setSyncAutomatically` on `contenResolver`
- `RequestSync` does nothing. The code on `onPerformSync` is never executed
- Internet is turned on.
- I am using a dummy authenticator to make this work. Read all I could find about sync adapter and still could not make this work.

Any hints on what to check?

Answer (score 0):

You must put the follow arguments in order to make `requestSync()` work.

```
Bundle settingsBundle = new Bundle();
settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
settingsBundle.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
ContentResolver.requestSync(mAccount, AUTHORITY, settingsBundle);
```

Comment: onPerformSync runs in a background thread right?! That could explain why log messages are not displayed in logcat?

Comment: Forgot to mention, tried the code you posted, still pending, but thanks anyway. I think the better will be give up on this and implement the same logic in a different way as many have done...

Comment: Yes, onPerformSync run in a background thread. Also, please post the code from onPerformSync, Manifest, xml.

Comment: HI GZ95 I gave up on sync adapter, it was too devil.Android 1 me 0. I know it has several advantages but it was really messy. I adopted a different strategy.  I've implemented the sync strategy in a intentService that runs on different events, periodic, broadcasts an so on. IT took me 20% of the time I wasted on syncAdapter. It is yet not finished but it's working now so I 'll stick to this.